# excel dynamic range, when the cell contains a formula taht returns an empty string ("")

Tags: excel, excel-formula, named-ranges

I am currently trying to create a named dynamic range.

Naming the range and selecting the range is fine using the following formula:
`$A$2:INDEX($1:$1048576,COUNTA($A:$A),COUNTA($1:$1))` - straight from the internet

However, as you can see from cells below row 14 these have a formula, that equal `""`, though `COUNTA` includes cells with formulas and hence the range is bigger than is required

I understand using `COUNTIF` is a way to get around this however I have struggled to get it to work properly at all.

What can I do to exclude rows with an empty string in column `A` and row `6` for the defined range

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to repolace `COUNTA(A:A)` with something that finds the last filled in cell.

One possibility would be

```
XMATCH(9999999,A:A,-1,2)
```

where 9999999 must be > any Ranking in your data.

Another option would be to use `FILTER`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your values in column A always start in row two, begin at 1 and increase by 1 for each rows you've got data then you can use `MAX($A:$A)+1` in place of `COUNTA($A:$A)`